# There are four possible operations of arity 1. What are they?

Tags: logic

I know negation is one but cant think of anything else? I need three more!

Comment: Negation, Identity, False and True.

Comment: user66118, I saw your moderator flag asking for the question to be deleted. Is there any reason you want to delete your question after getting several good answers? Please note that this site helps everyone online - even though you've got the answer now, if someone had the same question as you, we'd want them to be able to see the answer here as well.

Comment: @zevchonoles. I understand where you are coming from, but I would still like this post to be deleted. I think this is an amazing site! I will be a regular user from now on, but for now i would like it removed. Many thanks!

Comment: user66118 Zev's question is not "Do you want to delete this?" but "Why do you want to delete this?" Would you mind answering it?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If you mean truth functions, this is the same as the number of functions $\{ 0 , 1 \} \to \{ 0 , 1 \}$.  Forgetting about the "meaning" of these truth functions might make it easier.

Comment: so would tautology, contradiction and proposition truth tables also work to show arity 1 (unary) as well as negation obviously?

Comment: @user66118: Yup!  (if by "proposition truth tables" you  mean the identity function/operation.)

Comment: thank you so much! I thought i understood it but was going mad to find concrete answers! Thank u so much again!

Comment: @user66118: You're welcome.  I thought that after removing the meaning from the operations the answer would become a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

1) $f(0)=0,\ f(1)=0$

2) $f(0)=0,\ f(1)=1$

3) $f(0)=1,\ f(1)=0$ (negation)

4) $f(0)=1,\ f(1)=1$

Comment: Is $f(x)=x$ considered unary? If so (2) here could be named "identity" or something.

Answer (score 1):

The four possible unary operations are;

$T \mapsto T$
$F\mapsto   F$

$T \mapsto  F$
$F \mapsto  F$

$T \mapsto  T$
$F \mapsto  T$

$T \mapsto  F$
$F \mapsto  T$

Comment: Maybe you should explain how to read this 4-by-4 table.

Comment: Presumably each line is one unary truth function, and a line $TxFy$ is to be interpreted as the function that sends $T$ to $x$ and $F$ to $y$, but until you explain this, your answer is almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_i: \{T, F\} \to \{T, F\}$$
$$\text{_________________________}$$

$$f_1(T) = T, \quad f_1(F) = T\tag{T}$$

$$f_2(T) = T, \quad f_2(F) = F\tag{Identity}$$

$$f_3(T) = F, \quad f_3(F) = T\tag{Negation}$$

$$f_4(T) = F, \quad f_4(F) = F\tag{F}$$

$$\text{__________________________}$$

$$|\{f_i \mid f_i: \{T, F\} \to \{T, F\}\}| = 4$$

$f_1$ always returns the value of $T$: 
$f_2$ returns the truth value of the input.
$f_3$ returns the value of $\lnot$ (input)
$f_4$ always returns the value of $F$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by (input $\lor$ T), (input $\lor$ F), and (input $\land$ F).

Comment: Okay, lets try this again! ;-) (this is where the thing went south last time)! +1

Comment: hehehehehe... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you go outside the Boolean operations
to the reals,
there are an unlimited number of operations:
increment, reciprocal, factorial, trig,
blah, blah.

As usual, it's a requirements problem
(too many years in aerospace).